# Notepad++/Excel - how to copy each value x times in the list and keep the order

Tags: excel, notepad++

Hello i have this simple question:

i have a list of values in column, for example

- apple
- banana
- orange

i want copy each value x times and keep the order, for example 3 times, and list will look like this

- apple
- apple
- apple
- banana
- banana
- banana
- orange
- orange
- orange

possible in google docs or Notepad++?
real list is much longer, not in any alphabetical orders and need to be copied many times

i had some ideas but honestly idk

Comment: Copy, paste 3 times, and sort. But I assume your example is in alphabetical order by accident?

Comment: I believe it's possible in NP++ by using Replace with Regular Expressions.

Comment: UPD. real list is much longer, not in any alphabetical orders and need to be copied many times

Comment: @QuadroTony - Could you make that clear in your question?

Comment: yes i just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Sheets, you could use the following formula:

```
=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(range & CHAR(10), reps), CHAR(10))))
```

where **range** is the range of your data and **reps** is the number of repetitions you want for each element. Note that your data must be in a single column.

### Example:

Let's suppose this is your data and that you want each row to be repeated 3 times:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | apple |
| **2** | banana |
| **3** | orange |

You could use the following formula in cell B1:

```
=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A3 & CHAR(10), 3), CHAR(10))))
```

That would give you the following result:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | apple | apple |
| **2** | banana | apple |
| **3** | orange | apple |
| **4** |  | banana |
| **5** |  | banana |
| **6** |  | banana |
| **7** |  | orange |
| **8** |  | orange |
| **9** |  | orange |

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

[image: replace]

This is matching each line and then replacing each with 3 copies.

You would need to repeat the `\1\r\n` multiple times for each copy.

I've assumed Windows line endings, so adjust if you need to for Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks everyone, found solution

in Google Sheets i added column near my list with numbers from 1 to last(216 in my case)

added below list 216*x empty rows where x - how many times i want to copy all data

then i ctrl+c list and column with numbers

then highlighted all empty rows below my list and ctrl+v

after that just highlight resulted data and sort it

Answer (score 0):

In ***google-sheet*** you may try-

```
 =TOCOL(INDEX(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A3&"|",3),"|")))
```

[image]